# beautifulsoup doesn't show all ellements

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

i'm trying to parse Taobao website and get information about Goods (photo , text and link ) with BeautifulSoup.find but it doesn't find all classes.

```
url='https://xuanniwen.world.tmall.com/category-1268767539.htm?search=y&catName=%BC%D0%BF%CB#bd&view_op=citations_histogram'

def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text

html=get_html(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
z=soup.find("div",{"class":"J_TItems"})
```

z-is empty.
but for example:

```
z=soup.find("div",{"class":"skin-box-bd"})
len(z)
Out[196]: 3
```

works fine

Why this approach doesn't work? What should i do to get all information about good? i am using python 2.7

Comment: Try `soup.text.find("J_TItems")` and you will see it will say that there's no `J_TItems` at all in `soup`, what I think is happening is that the content you want to parse is not in the html, is in fact being built dynamically by JavaScript, you should look at selenium module for Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it looks like the items you want to parse are being built dynamically by JavaScript, that's why `soup.text.find("J_TItems")` returns `-1`, i.e. there's no "J_TItems" *at all* in the text. What you can do is use **[`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)** with a JS interpreter, for a headless browsing you can use **[`PhantomJS`](http://phantomjs.org/download.html)** like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url='https://xuanniwen.world.tmall.com/category-1268767539.htm?search=y&catName=%BC%D0%BF%CB#bd&view_op=citations_histogram'

browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
browser.get(url)
html = browser.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib') # I'd also recommend using html5lib
JTitems = soup.find("div", attrs={"class":"J_TItems"})
```

Note the items you want are inside each row defined by `<div class="item4line1">`, and there are 5 of them (you maybe only want the first three, because the other two are not really inside the main search, filtering that should not be difficult, a simple `rows = rows[2:]` do the trick):

```
rows = JTitems.findAll("div", attrs={"class":"item4line1"})
>>> len(rows)
5
```

Now notice each "Good" you mention in the question is inside a `<dl class="item">`, so you need to get them all in a `for` loop:

```
Goods = []    
for row in rows:
    for item in row.findAll("dl", attrs={"class":"item"}):
        Goods.append(item)
```

All there's left to do is to get "photo, text and link" as you mentioned, and this can be easily done accessing each item in `Goods` list, by inspection you can know how to get each of the information, for examples, for picture url a simple one-line would be:

```
>>> Goods[0].find("dt", class_='photo').a.img["src"]
'//img.alicdn.com/bao/uploaded/i3/TB19Fl1SpXXXXbsaXXXXXXXXXXX_!!0-item_pic.jpg_180x180.jpg'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot i really appreciate your help . Maybe you can  tell me, how could i understand which approach to use for some hidden content JavaScript, Ajax etc while i'm trying parsing website.

Comment: @egorkh I'm glad to help! I'd say going for `selenium` and loading JavaScript is always the best option, but you can tell if you need that or not by inspecting the html source code of the page you want to scrape, if what you want is not there but it's in the inspect code window, you'll need JavaScript parsing!